# Fix broken link /etc/extlinux.conf

Tags: linux, boot

The link /etc/extlinux.conf is broken

```
[root@p6t etc]# file /etc/extlinux.conf
/etc/extlinux.conf: broken symbolic link to `../boot/extlinux/extlinux.conf
```

System boots just fine without it.

How to fix this broken link on RedHat based systems?

Comment: Do you use extlinux to boot? If not ignore the broken symlink.